# How to intercept Hardware Keyboard Buttons in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am writing an Android App using Xamarin.Android.
I have to detect the hardware keyboard buttons (since my target device is a flip-phone), but I don't know how to do it in Xamarin.

In java it was something like this:

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
 switch(keyCode)
{
 case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP: 
     Toast.makeText(this, "Volume Up pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true; 
   case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
     Toast.makeText(this, "Volume Down pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     return true;
 }
 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Is there any way to detect/intercept keyboard buttons? some code example please?

Thank you all!

**EDIT**

I am looking for something that will allow me to have access to every single hardware button of the keyboard (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,#,*, call btn, endCall btn, etc.)

**SECOND EDIT**

Found what might be the problem...the code works perfectly, but since my app is a Launcher when I press number keys the dialer starts, any idea on how redirect the dialing to an activity I create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my final solution to intercept numpad keys on android devices. I hope this will help somebody else in the future.

```
 [Activity(Label = "PhoneTask", LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionDial, Intent.ActionCallButton, Intent.ActionView },
         Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault },
         DataScheme = "tel")]
```

Just added this piece of code above my activity class and now, when I press these buttons on a laucher app, I am redirected to my activity.

Answer (score 1):

Put this method in your activity:

```
public override bool OnKeyDown (Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
    {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case Keycode.VolumeUp:
            Toast.MakeText (this, "Volume Up pressed", ToastLength.Long).Show ();
            return true;
            break;
        case Keycode.VolumeDown:
            Toast.MakeText (this, "Volume Down pressed", ToastLength.Long).Show ();
            return true;
            break;
        }
        return base.OnKeyDown (keyCode, e);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks BUKA, but I was looking for something that will allow me to have access to every single hardware button of the keyboard(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,#,*). I will edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: Keycode has the property called Numpad from which you are catching the numbers. If you want to catch the (# and *) you should check the modifiers,
this will catch the '#'
`if (Keycode == Keycode.Numpad3 && e.Modifiers == MetaKeyStates.ShiftOn) {
   }`

Comment: Tested, but does not work. When keyboard buttons are pressed, the dialer starts, my goal is to block the dialer to start and show the Toast instead. Any idea? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that is possible? Maybe the keyboard input isn't even going through your app at all.

Comment: I would think that the capture/redirection of hardware dialer buttons would not be allowed as it could block emergency calls...

Comment: @KaiBrummund I was thinking the same thing...but there must be a way, I hope.

Comment: @RobertN Do you think there is a way to capture that input? Maybe root? (Consider that it is a private app, not for the playStore)